# why does my .NET 2.0 application crash under .NET 4.0 when I use a OleDbDataAdapter object without an OleDBConnection object?

Tags: .net, excel, .net-4.0, ado.net

This is a .NET 2.0 application written using VS 2005. It works fine on systems running .NET 2.0, but hard crashes on systems running .NET 4.0. Here's the critical section of the code:

```
      string selectCommand1 = ....
      string connectionString1 = ....
      using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand1, connectionString1))
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(table1);
            }
            catch
            {
               MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }

      string selectCommand2 = ....
      string connectionString2 = ....
      using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand2, connectionString2))
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(table2);
            }
            catch
            {
               MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

Again, it works under .NET 2.0, crashes under .NET 4.0

ConnectionStrings 1 & 2 reference different .xls files.

I found that the way around this problem is to declare and initialize a field variable of type OleDbConnection, set the ConnectionString property and Open() it before the OleDbDataAdapter's using statement. As so:

```
 OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

  .......

        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString1;
        connection.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand1, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(table1);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString2;
        connection.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand2, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(table2);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

It's hard to believe that this is the reason why my app was hard crashing (no error messages) under .NET 4.0, but after removing lines of code one at a time and recompiling over and over I found that to be the cause of the problem.

I'm glad I solved the problem, but I'm not satisfied with the fact that the first code won't work with .NET 4.0.

Can someone please explain why .NET 4.0 doesn't like to work with code like the one above?

Comment: According to MSDN, the OleDbDataAdapter constructor you're using does not open the implicitly created connection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f8y4737%28v=vs.100%29 However, if you look at the 2.0 version of that documentation, it gives the same warning.

Comment: that's interesting. still does not answer the question of why it works under .net 2.0 but not .net 4.0

Comment: Have you checked the windows event logs to see if there is any clues for the crash (since you stated there is no explicit error message? Also, you are just doing a catch... what happens if you do `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }`?

Comment: Jason, as you suggested I viewed the event log. I found the following: Log Name: Application. Source: Application Hang. The program <my program> stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel. When I click on the details tab and check under binaries it says "C.r.o.s.s.-.t.h.r.e.a.d ...." How is this a Cross Thread exception? And how come a) it is not thrown with .NET 2.0 and b) it is throw but not caught with .NET 4.0?

Comment: I studied the event logs and found a reference to vrfcore.dll. Turns out it is related to "Application Verifier". I uninstalled that program from my PC and my app now works properly. Still weird that I didn't have this problem with .NET 2.0. Anyway, at least I got my app to work. I still wonder why this Application Verifier program caused problems with .NET 4.0

Comment: It's a bit unusual that a third party app would be messing around with the .net libraries like that... But if uninstalling it fixed your problem, now I have to wonder what /other/ damage that app caused. Who made the offending app? I'm thinking about putting a warning out through my shop about it because I've heard that name getting bandied about here.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, it doesn't matter that the constructor doesn't open the connection, as `DbDataAdapter.Fill` will [open the connection if it's not already open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.100%29). It also closes it again afterwards (if it wasn't open beforehand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was "Application Verifier". Uninstalling it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your original code (without connection.open), have you initialized the tables prior to calling `adapter.Fill(table1)` ?

```
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand1, connectionString1))
    {
        using (System.Data.DataTable table1 = new System.Data.DataTable()) {

            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(table1);
            }
            catch
            {
               MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
    }
```