# what's the proper way to handle multiple connections to multiple Excel files in ADO.NET 4.0?

Tags: excel, .net-4.0, ado.net, .net-2.0, oledb

I have a piece of code written using VS 2005 that works fine in computers running .NET 2.0 but hard crashes in computers running .NET 4.0.

The section of hte code that's causing the problem is a call to the DataAdapter's Fill() method. The code looks as follows:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    string connectionString = ... //connects to excelfile1.xls
    string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

    using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dt1);
    }

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    connectionString = ... //connects to excelfile2.xls

    using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString))
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dt2);
    }
}
```

Several things happen if I make slight modifications to the code:

1. if I remove the two calls to OleDbConnection.Open(), the code will work just fine with .NET 2.0, but hard crash with .NET 4.0.
2. if I remove only the second call to OleDbConnection.Open(), the code will work fine with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0. Alas, I need to retrieve data from two separate excel files and fill two separate DataTables each time the event is fired.
3. if I use both calls to OleDbConnection.Open(), as shown in the code above, the code will work fine with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0, BUT hard crash with .NET 4.0 the second or third time the user clicks on the button and the procedure runs.

My guess is that .NET 4.0 manages connections differently than .NET 2.0 and I'm missing some very important step.

Can someone please tell how I should write the above code in such a way that it will work fine under .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0?

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438952/why-does-my-net-2-0-application-crash-under-net-4-0-when-i-use-a-oledbdataadap), wrap the call in a `try/catch` block ensuring you include `(Exception ex)`. This should at least let you know what the exception is. And when in doubt, use the windows event viewer to lookup the exception.

Comment: try/catch block does not catch the exception. catch all by itself does not catch it. catch(Exception e) does not catch it either.

Comment: Jason, as you suggested I viewed the event log. I found the following: Log Name: Application. Source: Application Hang. The program <my program> stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel. When I click on the details tab and check under binaries it says "C.r.o.s.s.-.t.h.r.e.a.d ...." How is this a Cross Thread exception? And how come a) it is not thrown with .NET 2.0 and b) it is throw but not caught with .NET 4.0?

Comment: I studied the event logs and found a reference to vrfcore.dll. Turns out it is related to "Application Verifier". I uninstalled that program from my PC and my app now works properly. Still weird that I didn't have this problem with .NET 2.0. Anyway, at least I got my app to work. I still wonder why this Application Verifier program caused problems with .NET 4.0

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out the issue (even though it's still not quite a full explanation).

Comment: Can you tell me if you are using the Jet or Ace provider in your connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was "Application Verifier".